# click to call phone extension smartphone

Tags: html, hyperlink, phone-number, tel

Looking to call a phone number and extension from clickable link in a smartphone, example (212)-555-1212  Ext.456 and then an extension number

I have tried

```
<a href="tel:(212)-555-1212,456">Call me</a>
```

and also

```
<a href="tel:(212)-555-1212p456">Call me</a>
```

Both resulted in phone (Galaxy Note 4) calling (212)-555-1212**7**456

I could not find how to add the extension number after a pause.

Answer (score 2):

Try this-
Use ext attribute

```
<a href="tel:+44-1234-56788;ext=88">+44-1234-56788</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="tel:12345678;ext=123">
```

Answer (score 0):

On Android and iPhone last version work this:

```
<a href="tel:+7-999-999-99-99,,1234">Click</a>
```